# $vuetify.goTo won't scroll within a v-card component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component with a v-card. I placed a simple button into the card title area.  When I click I see that the method fires, it shows in the console.  But, the card never scrolls.  If I typo the class name, I get an error so the goTo appears to do something as it does not find the class.  Without the typo, no error but the card body never scrolls.

```
<v-btn 
    x-small 
    class="ma-0 ml-6" 
    color="red" 
    dark
    dense 
    @click="gotoSelectedVendor()"
>
  GoTo
</v-btn>
```

...

```
gotoSelectedVendor() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log("gotoSelectedVendor");
  this.$vuetify.goTo(".selectedRow");
},
```

Does $vuetify.goTo only work to scroll the page? Does it not scroll the contents of a div?

Answer (score 10):

From the [goto](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/services/goto/index.ts#L16) service, the `goTo` function take 2 arguments which are `VuetifyGoToTarget` and `GoToOptions`.

And the `GoToOptions` contains the `container` property which is set to `document.scrollingElement` by default.

So you can do something like:

```js
gotoSelectedVendor() {
  this.$vuetify.goTo(".selectedRow", { container: ".yourCard" });
}
```

You can also use refs instead of class selector:

```js
gotoSelectedVendor() {
  this.$vuetify.goTo(this.$refs.selectedRow, { container: this.$refs.card });
}
```

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/yjpq03da/).

Comment: Something is just odd.  If I say typo the container class, I get an error that the container cannot be found. I correct the spelling, try again and no error. Also my console.log works, so I know the method is being fired. Something is happening. However nothing scrolls.  Is the scroll in the datatable or is the card contents scrolling?

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere, maybe. If I remove the height from the data table and put a fixed height on the card, the goTo works.  However, now my card title scrolls out of view.

Comment: Ok, it was a matter of finally figuring out the correct container to target:  container: ".v-data-table__wrapper"

Comment: Shouldn't it be rather `this.$refs.something` instead of `$refs.something`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that goTo is a somewhat capricious function. Especially regarding the specification of the container. It did not work until I checked in the browser console where the scroll event is placed and that is on the `div.v-card__text`. Then it works as shown below. This function works now even if you use it inside a dialog. And do not forget to set `ref="myCard"` on the v-card element.

```
gotoSelectedVendor() {
        let wrapper = this.$refs['myCard'].$el.querySelector('div.v-card__text')
        this.$vuetify.goTo('.selectedRow', { container: wrapper })
    },
```