# How to programmatically scroll an element instead of a page in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Using vuetify: I have a v-card on top of a page which contains content and scrolls independent of the page. I need to scroll to the bottom of the cards scrollable content when I click a button.

I have the page scrolling on button click, but I need the page to stand still and only scroll the content of the card.

```
 <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-text>stay</v-text> 
    <v-container
      >
        <v-layout
          align-center
          justify-center
        >
          <v-flex xs12>
        <v-toolbar color="cyan" dark >
          <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
          <v-toolbar-title>Scroll content of this card on click</v-toolbar-title>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-card>
        <v-btn
            fab
            dark
            fixed
            bottom
            right
            color="primary"
            @click="$vuetify.goTo('#bottom')"
          >
            <v-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
  
          <v-card-title primary-title>
            <card
                  style="max-height: 100px"                                 class="overflow-y-auto scroll-y"
                 >

              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse dignissim elit eu nisl aliquam consectetur. Mauris laoreet arcu dignissim justo vestibulum commodo. Sed eu leo quam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec aliquam vel nunc ac lacinia. Sed lobortis mollis urna sit amet posuere. Maecenas elementum odio lectus, quis porttitor ipsum feugiat in. Fusce dictum elit metus, eget consectetur sapien feugiat quis.

Aenean eget consequat ex. Nullam dictum ante mi, at commodo tortor gravida at. Fusce dolor purus, facilisis sit amet sem pellentesque, molestie volutpat lacus. Aliquam molestie et urna vel lacinia. Nulla facilisi. Aenean dignissim pretium tellus, id tincidunt odio fermentum quis. Vivamus id orci nisi. Aenean vitae ex vitae dolor interdum sodales id sit amet lorem. Sed quis lacus euismod nibh porttitor blandit. Sed semper nibh in lacus tincidunt, in commodo lorem tempus. Fusce condimentum sodales quam. Nullam maximus auctor interdum. Sed id sagittis felis.

Vestibulum venenatis felis sed lectus fringilla tempus. Quisque eu magna placerat magna tempus vehicula. Integer id feugiat purus. Curabitur vitae vehicula arcu. Etiam nec arcu urna. Suspendisse et ullamcorper metus. In ut fermentum arcu. Donec eu purus vehicula, semper arcu iaculis, faucibus turpis. Etiam in nulla blandit, tempus mauris quis, pharetra diam. Pellentesque nec molestie ipsum. Aenean eget tortor augue.

</card>
        <v-div id="bottom">
        </v-div>
        </v-card-title>  
        </v-card>
          <v-card style="margin:10px 0px; height:1000px;">
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
 
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Vuetify has a v-scroll directive - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/scroll/

It also has programatic scrolling - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/scrolling/

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140352/vuetify-goto-wont-scroll-within-a-v-card-component) help you?

Comment: Yep, this solved it! Thanks so much for pointing me in this direction!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working based on User 28's link. Thank you!

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140352/vuetify-goto-wont-scroll-within-a-v-card-component)